# Setting Labels from resource files in different dlls depending on user running app?

Tags: c#, winforms, resx

I require labels to have different values depending on who is running the application, so I thought about creating a dll for each user type and in the dll, there would be a resource file that would hold the labels values.  At runtime, depending on which dll was in a specified directory, it would use resources found in the dll to set the labels values.

```
1) Are multiple dll's necessary in this case?
2) If it is multiple dll's, is MEF or something similar necessary here or can it 
   be done without it?
```

Comment: This information should be stored in a database and the data should be fetch from the database as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution  is Definately Overkill. How do you intend to interchange dlls for deployment? Do you have control over the package that each user will be downloading / installing?

My First Impression is that it would me much easier use / maintain a class that has string properties that return different set values depending in the input parameter.

i.e.

```
public String FirstResourceEntry
{
    get
    {
        switch(userTypeEnum)
        { 
          case userType1:
               return "SetValue1";
               break;
          case: userType2:
                return "SetValue2";
                break;
    }
}
```

This way is a little more tightly coupled to your app as it will require a rebuild if you want to change values, but wit will also allow you to distribute the same app / file set to all potential users.